# replace a number random form a string in PHP

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<?php

$source[]="clock=1,time=1,stamp=3,color=33";
$source[]="clock=2,time=1,stamp=1,color=61";

$label="clock";

$what=$label."=(\d)";
$this="clock=0";

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
{
$new_source=preg_replace( $what,$this,$source[$i],$count);
echo $new_source;
};

?>
```

I need to replace $label=1; or $label=x with $label=0 but the x is variable.

Comment: What is the problem? AFAIK this code does just that.

Comment: From the look of it, it's actually replacing `clock=1` with `clock=clock=0`

Comment: No, it is not. It is matching clock=n and replacing it with clock=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off the bat, don't use $this. Rename it to, for example, $replacement. $this is a reserved variable in PHP5.

Next, you don't need $count in pre_replace.

Finally, wrap $what in a delimiter (such as /).

`$new_source=preg_replace( '/'.$what.'/',$replacement,$source[$i]);`

Comment: Thanx I'll try this right away. PS: $this was just for example :) i don't use it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$source[]="clock=1,time=1,stamp=3,color=33";
$source[]="clock=2,time=1,stamp=1,color=61";

$label="clock";

$what="/$label=(\d)/";
$to="clock=0";

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
{
$new_source=preg_replace( $what,$to,$source[$i]);
echo $new_source;
};
```

This is now correct. The problems were:

- You used a variable named $this to store the replace target string, which is incorrect because PHP refers to the current object with the variable $this in an object-oriented context.
- You passed a parameter named $count to preg_replace which had no value.